# Added new field to table and to stored procedure, now procedure returns no results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-express

I recently added a `Deleted` column to my table and then wanted to add an additional where clause but now I'm not getting any results anymore (it returned results before I added the `deleted` column)

```
SELECT 
    tblEquipment.*, tblUsers.* 
FROM 
    tblEquipment 
INNER JOIN 
    tblUsers ON tblEquipment.UserID = tblUsers.ID 
WHERE  
    (UPPER(tblUsers.Dept) = 'ASPIRE' OR UPPER(tblUsers.Dept) = 'DEVELOPMENT') 
    AND (AssetType = 'WORKSTATION' OR AssetType = 'LAPTOP') 
    AND (tblEquipment.Deleted != 1)  
ORDER BY 
    Username
```

thanks for any help

Comment: microsoft sqlserver 2008 express, i got my results until i added the deleted not equal to 1 part, currently deleted is null on all records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Deleted` is `NULL` for every record, your condition should be:

```
AND (tblEquipment.Deleted != 1 OR tblEquipment.Deleted IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you haven't populated your new column, so every record has NULL as the value there.  Depending on how your RDMS evaluates NULL, the

```
tblEquipment.Deleted != 1
```

is probably the culprit.

UPDATE:

The following should fix your problem:

```
ISNULL(tblEquipment.Deleted,0) != 1
```

Comment: how can I alter this so it will show the record of null and anything not 1 ?

Comment: Updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: I would advise to not use `ISNULL` here, since it will make the use of an index on that column impossible

Comment: @Lamak Great point there.  Didn't take that into consideration.